# Dell XPS 17 9730 No sound, only dummy output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I can't get the sound on my Dell XPS 17 9730 to work. It's stuck on dummy output. The sound controller is an Intel Corporation Device 51ca. Alsa mixer lists it as sof-hda-dsp. I'm using Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the exact same laptop but with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I've got the same issue with 9730 on Pop-OS kernel 6.2.6-76060206-generic. Bluetooth headphone audio works as a weak workaround though. Anybody found a fix/workaround or know the source of the issue?

Comment: Also, sound works on Kubuntu 22.04 (but not 23.04) live usb.